How would I go about creating a "recently opened" feature like VSCode.dev?
If you where to be on chromium and look at VSCode.dev you can see that is stores what files you have opened with it "recently". Even if you close the tab and come back to the site a couple days later. I've been searching online for how one would go about it but I cant find any info, and when I search the VS code repository I'm only getting IEnumerables (I'm not much of a typescript person) that have similar names to the feature, but nothing about how the feature is done.

I've found the answer after searching more, it was not what you suggested but it was actually question 65928613
